# In vuejs, why I need to use nextTick while use mounted hooks?

Tags: vue.js

As the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#ready-replaced) said, I need to use nextTick to confirm `$el` ready, but in another [page](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted), it roughly means that the `$el` has been ready while `mounted` called. So, why need to use nextTick while use mounted hooks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe `el` is indeed mounted when `mounted` hook is called. Real usage for `nextTick` is described [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Async-Update-Queue). It's mainly used when you need a direct DOM access (which is not recommended btw) immediately after changing something affecting your DOM in your code. Check this code:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    text: 'one'
  },
  components: {
    'child' : {
      template: `<p>{{ text }}</p>`,
      props: ['text']
    }
  },
  mounted: function() {
    console.log(document.querySelector('p').textContent); // 'one'
    this.text = 'two'; // assign new value
    console.log('after text has changed: ');
    console.log(document.querySelector('p').textContent); // still 'one'
    this.$nextTick(function() {
      console.log('nextTick: ', document.querySelector('p').textContent); // now 'two' after 'nextTick'
    })
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <child :text="text"></child>
</div>
```

So, I guess migration docs are misleading in this case.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer.